# How do I network 2 Google CloudRun Instances on the same VPC network, one externally facing one not?

Tags: google-cloud-run

I started working at a startup and we are working on deconstructing a monolithic application deployed to cloudRun and now have another service on cloudRun. To start on our dev instances we didn't have security for the new service, but before we go to production we want to add security.

For the monolithic app, we have it set up:

```
Ingress Control: All
Using Serverless VPC Access connector: default-internal
Network: default
Subnet: 10.8.0.0/28
Traffic routing: route only requests to private IPs to the VPC
```

For the other service we have:

```
Ingress Control: All
Using Serverless VPC Access connector: default-external
Network: default
Subnet: ourcompany-subnet-external(10.124.0.0/28)
Traffic routing: route all traffic to the VPC
```

However, what I want to do is set the Ingress for the other service to Internal and have the monolithic service still be able to access the other one. I think the issue is when this was set up they were given 2 different connectors which have different subnets, and that is probably the problem. What would you change to get the setup I'm looking for and what would be the best practices around this?

So far I haven't messed with it much, just googled the issue and didn't completely understand yet what I'm looking at. I just started with Google Cloud and it my last company I had a DevOps team that dealt with the networking. At this startup, I'm also DevOps...

Comment: Connectors are not transitive. That means traffic will go to/from the VPC but will not be routed to another network.

Comment: @JohnHanley So does that mean what I think it means because these are different subnets while both on the same "network"(Default) they will not be routed to each other? My coworker tried putting them on the same subnet but that still didn't work.

Comment: A connector is a VM that routes traffic from one network (Cloud Run) to another network (VPC). You can do this: `Cloud Run -> VPC` but you cannot do this: `Cloud Run -> VPC -> Cloud Run` via connectors. Cloud Run is in a different network (Google's) and not part of your VPC. Putting them in the same subnet does not change the routing issue. Cloud Run traffic is routed to that subnet, it is not part of that subnet.